# what are the requirements for my country to be an official member of ROS?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[image description http://www.ros.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/user_map.jpg](http://www.ros.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/12/user_map.jpg)

I imagine that this image represents the countries with most ROS members. I am from Peru and the ROS community is poor but I would like to know how my country can appear on this image and what are the requirementes !!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267722/what-are-the-requirements-for-my-country-to-be-an-official-member-of-ros?/) by [irosenof](https://answers.ros.org/users/31390/irosenof/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-07-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are no requirements, and I've never heard of countries "being official members of ROS". That would be strange as well, as 'ROS' is a software framework.

As to the image you show: that is the *user map* as of December 2013, which is rather old, and was made based on user contributed data (so only people / institutions / companies that happened to tell others they were using ROS are shown on it).

For a more up-to-date version, see the [ROS Users of the World](http://metrorobots.com/rosmap.html) map that @DLu maintains. It already has one dot for Peru: *San Pablo Catholic University*.

Note that that map is *also* based on user input: just submit a Pull Request to [DLu/ros_map](https://github.com/DLu/ros_map) to get included.

---

Summary: you don't need to belong to some "ROS club" to be considered a ROS user. Just using it is enough. If you want to show others that you are using it, then you could consider contributing to the ROS Map (linked above).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-07-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2